# Stacking two hboxes

Tags: boxes

I am trying to write the macro `\foo{...}{...}` that creates an hbox made up of both `\hbox{#1}` and `\hbox{#2}`, such that both hboxes are stacked one on top of the other. The width of the resulting hbox should be the *maximum* of the two hboxes. The arguments to the macro are in plain mode (i.e., not in math mode).

I'm not very good with raw TeX. Can someone please help?

Comment: Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is an old question, it looked like a good place to highlight the various capabilities of my new `stackengine` package in one place, rather than (as I have been doing) on a piecemeal basis.  All the gap/shift distances are specifiable, as well. [EDIT: This MWE revised to use V2.0 syntax, which was implemented to allow stackgap lengths to be scalable with fontsize.  The V2.0 package was submitted to CTAN 7/11/13]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\x{\rule[-.2pt]{2ex}{.4pt}}
\parindent 0pt\parskip 1em
\def\blmark{\x\stackengine{-.9ex}{B}{\rule{.35ex}{0pt}L}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}\x}
\begin{document}

The \textsf{stackengine} package:

SHORT STACKS (constant inter-item gap):
\def\stacktype{S}\setstackgap{S}{4pt}
\\with center alignment

\blmark
\stackon{macro}{stackon}\x
\stackunder{stackunder}{macro}\x
\Shortstack{this is the Shortstack macro}\x
\Shortunderstack{the Shortunderstack macro}\x
\blmark

LONG STACKS (constant inter-baseline distance):
\def\stacktype{L}\setstackgap{L}{1.1\baselineskip}
\\with left alignment\def\stackalignment{l}

\blmark
\stackon{macro}{stackon}\x
\stackunder{stackunder}{macro}\x
\Longstack{this is the Longstack macro}\x
\Longunderstack{the Longunderstack macro}\x
\blmark

\def\useanchorwidth{T}

use anchorwidth for
{\Longunderstack{this is the Longunderstack macro}} 
stack rather than the full stackwidth

\def\stackalignment{c}
\def\stacktype{L}
In addition, the \textsf{stackengine} package does baseline 
\belowbaseline[6pt]{shifts}, as well as 
\tllap{tl}\bllap{bl}lapp\tclap{tc}\bclap{bc}ing\trlap{tr}\brlap{br}, 
and insetting (\bottominset{*}{O}{-2pt}{}verlapping) text and
\def\stackalignment{r}
\topinset{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
         {\fbox{\rule[-1.5cm]{0pt}{3cm}Figures~~~~~}}{2pt}{4pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In general you can stack `\hbox`es inside a `\vbox` (which should be placed inside a `\hbox` as well if you want to use the result in horizontal mode), like Gonzalo Medina shows in his nice answer.

There are also some macros and packages for this:

- `\shortstack{foo\\bar}` will stack `foo` over `bar` (adding `\strut`s might be a good idea to get correct baseline skip)
- The small `minibox` package provides `\minibox`:
  `\minibox{foo\\bar}`
  It also accepts an optional argument `[l]`, `[c]` or `[r]` to align the lines.

Both macros allow for more than two hbox'es/lines.

Comment: If you try \foo{some}{test text} \foo{some}{test text} \foo{some}{test text} then Gonzalo's solution does not work -- the stacks are placed one under the other, rather then to their side. Now the minibox package works just great, and I created a wrapper macro that does just what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Mayer Goldberg: Note that `\minibox` itself is just a wrapper around `tabular`: `\long macro:[#1]#2->\begin {tabular}{@{}#1@{}} #2 \end {tabular}`

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\foo[2]{%
  \hbox{\vbox{\hbox{#1}\hbox{#2}}}
}

\begin{document}

\foo{some}{test text}

\end{document}
```

or (more in TeX's spirit):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\foo#1#2{%
  \hbox{\vbox{\hbox{#1}\hbox{#2}}}
}

\begin{document}

\foo{some}{test text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not quite: The problem with this is that I need these foo-stacks to be printed one after the other on the same line. So I might use it as \foo{in}{in} \foo{principio}{the beginning} \foo{creavit}{created (3rd, sg)} \foo{Deus}{God} \word{caelum}{heaven} \word{et}{and} \word{terram.}{earth.} I'm trying to use this for inter-linear texts.

Comment: @Meyer That's because you're using it before entering horizontal mode (i.e., before properly beginning a paragraph).  You can take care of this case by changing it to `\def\foo#1#2{\leavevmode\hbox{\vbox{\hbox{#1}\hbox{#2}}}}`, i.e., just insert `\leavevmode`.