# Specify vertical separation in arrays

Tags: arrays, vertical-spacing

Currently, I specify vertical separation with for example `\def\arraystretch{1.4}`, but I find that I need to adjust the argument to the environment depending on how high the rows are, which is tedious, and I can't adjust the height dynamically inside of the array. For example, the following array has rows with very different heights and would benefit from something that simulated a dynamic arraystretch:

```
$$
\def\arraystretch{2.0}
\begin{array}{rl}
q = & \text{some expression with low height} \\
= & \text{some expression with the same low height} \\
= & \def\arraystretch{1.0} \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{two} \\
  \text{matrices,} \\
  \text{each} \\
  \text{with} \\
  \end{pmatrix} \\
= & \def\arraystretch{1.0} \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{relatively} \\
  \text{large} \\
  \text{height} \\
  \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{array}
$$
```

[image]

Even though the `arraystretch` has been set so high that the spacing between the first two rows has become too large, there is still no vertical spacing at all between the last two rows. This highly varying spacing between rows is undesirable.

For columns, there is `\arraycolsep`, which creates a uniform horizontal separation, but I haven't found any corresponding variable for vertical separation between rows (i.e., the distance between the bottom of one row and the top of the next row). The only way I know to achieve the latter is by choosing a small `arraystretch` and adding a newline by using `\\` between the rows, but this creates a spacing that is too high.

So, is there some way to get a uniform, customizable vertical separation between rows in the `array` environment?

Comment: Lest you first compile the table measuring the height and depth of each row, I don't see a way.

Comment: You can see the `cellspace` package with option `[math]`; iy defines minimal vertical spacings  at the top and boyyom of cells in rows with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` by default, or `C` if you load `siunitx` or whatever letter you please  with the option `[column=…]`.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what kind of tables you are trying to build?  Maybe provide typical examples?

Comment: The reason I ask is that `stackengine` and `tabstackengine` can build arrays with either a fixed baselineskip or with a fixed gap between rows.  But what it cannot do is give a separate eq number to each line of the stack.  It is also limited in what it can do with lines between array elements.  So, depending on the specifics of your need, the package may or may not offer some relief.  Here is a quick overview answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12726/stacking-two-hboxes/120878#120878

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I've added an example, but for some reason the code I've added won't turn in to a math equation ... why? Do I use the wrong syntax for instantiating a LaTeX math expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't need separate rows numbered and various vertical and horizontal lines between rows and columns, the `stackengine` package provides "short" stacks that give equal gap between adjacent row data, account for the height of the row content.  Here, I set the gap to 9pt, which can be adjusted.

The stacking gap will not affect the row spacing within the `pmatrix`, only the gap between adjacent rows of text and pmatrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{S}{9pt}% ADJUST THE INTER-ROW GAP HERE
\[
\alignShortstack{
q = & \text{some expression with low height} \\
= & \text{some expression with the same low height} \\
= & {\begin{pmatrix}
  \text{some} \\
  \text{expression} \\
  \text{with} \\
  \text{great} \\
  \text{height} \\
  \end{pmatrix}}\\
= & {\begin{pmatrix}
  \text{relatively} \\
  \text{large} \\
  \text{height} \\
  \end{pmatrix}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

To answer a comment from the OP, if one wants different alignments, don't use `\alignShortstack`, but `\tabbedShortstack{...}` (if all columns have the same alignment), or `\tabularShortstack{<alignments>}{...}` to specify particular alignments.  And yes, the number of columns can be extended, as well as the intercolumn gap being specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{S}{9pt}% ADJUST THE INTER-ROW GAP HERE
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}% INTER COLUMN GAP
\[
\tabularShortstack{rcr}{
q = & \text{some expression} & \text{with low height} \\
= & \text{some expression with} & \text{/the same low height} \\
= & {\begin{pmatrix}
  \text{some} \\
  \text{expression} \\
  \text{with} \\
  \text{great} \\
  \text{height} \\
  \end{pmatrix}}
  & more\\
= & {\begin{pmatrix}
  \text{relatively} \\
  \text{large} \\
  \text{height} \\
  \end{pmatrix}}
  & even~more}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I specify how the content should be aligned within the various columns somehow? Now you have simply removed `[rl]`, which is not what I want. And can I use more that two columns? This macro seems to solve the vertical separation problem, but instead introduces two new problems which are more severe.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever The answer is yes, more columns can be added and different alignments specified.  See the **SUPPLEMENT** portion of my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, `tabbedShortstack` seems to work most of the times, but it fails if I try to nest an `array` environment or another `tabbedShortstack` inside of it. Do you know if this is supposed to work?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever It works if (as in the above examples), you enclose the array in braces: for example, `{\begin{array}{cc}
  a & b \\
  aaa & b \\
  a& bbb \\
  \end{array}}` works fine as an element of a `\tabbedShortstack`.

Comment: Great, that seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: While `\setstackgap` works in the example you provided, it doesn't do anything in my project. I have tried changing the parameter values but no matter what crazy values I set them to, it is like the macro has never even been called (I can't make anything move even a pixel). Do you have any idea of what could be the cause of that? (`\setstacktabulargap` still works as expected, though.)

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever If I take either of my MWEs and change the `9pt` short-stack-gap to, for example, `19pt`, it results in a changed stacking gap.  So I don't know what to tell you other than to make sure you are using the precise syntax called for.  The other question is if you are using other `stackengine` macros elsewhere in the document, that may be resetting the stack gap.  If so, you may need to issue the `\setstackgap{S}{...}` immediately before the stacking invocation.

Comment: Well, I am issuing it right before i start the `equation` environment in which I use the `tabularShortstack` macro. I may try to reduce the document in that case to see exactly what is causing this behavior.

Comment: Do you by any change know how to specify the alignment of a `\tabularShortstack` with its surrounding environment, corresponding to setting the optional `pos` arguments for the [`array`](http://www.ctex.org/documents/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-202.html) environment, if that is possible?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever I do not think I understand your question, though I am not a frequent user of the `array` environment. The `stackengine` macros only specify alignment within the confines of their own argument.  If you are trying to align a stack within a larger `array` context, it would seem to me that the parameters of the `array` environment control the alignment of its constituents, including any included stacks.

Comment: I'll give you an example: Let's say that I have a `\tabularShortstack` where each row begins with a `=`, because I'm rewriting a mathematical expression to my liking. Eventually, I need to expand the expression, which makes it really long, so that it doesn't fit on one row. There are also parts inside of the expression I want to line up horizontally, so I nest a `\tabularShortstack` inside of the first one. Now, I want what is just before that `\tabularShortstack` to be vertically aligned with the first row in it, and not with the middle of it. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Still guessing at what you might mean?  Maybe this?  `\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABbinary
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
 A & B\\
CC & D \tabularShortunderstack{cll}{
  = & EE &+ F\\
  = & G &+HH}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}  `

Comment: Thanks! `\tabularShortunderstack` did it for me!

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Great!  You can always refer to the documentation: https://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine and https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine

Comment: Thank you; I know about the `tabstackengine` documentation. Do you use it a lot yourself? Personally, I find it a little bit difficult to find what you are looking for. For example, I took I look in there to read more about `\tabularShortunderstack` (to see what the main difference was between that and `\tabularShortstack` was), but the only documentation that I could find for that macro was the definition, which itself calls another macro called `\Shortunderstack`, which isn't even documented there.

Comment: However, now that you mentioned that there is a related library called `stackengine`, I took a look in that documentation, and that does have a section about `Shortunderstack`. So I might give that a try. Thank you.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever The basics of stacking are driven by the `stackengine` package.  The `tabstackengine` package is a front end that enables column tabbing within the stack.

Comment: Aha! That is good to know. Thank you!

Comment: Hm, when I try the example you provided again now (in the comment from Nov 6), it works as it stands, but if I replace the `array` environment with the `\tabularShortstack` macro, which I prefer, it breaks. Do you know why?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Unfortunately, with the current incarnation of `tabstackengine`, nesting of tabbed stacks does not usually work.  The workaround is to save the inner stack in advance, and regurgitate it in the outer box: `\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tabstackengine} 
\TABstackMath 
\TABbinary 
\setstacktabulargap{0pt} 
\begin{document} 
\[ 
\savestack\tmp{\tabularShortunderstack{cll}{   = & EE &+ F\\   = & G &+HH}}
\tabularShortunderstack{cc}{A & B\\ CC & D \tmp} 
\] 
\end{document}`

Comment: Okay, that's not ideal since you have to write the content of it somewhere else in your code, but it seems to do the job. Thank you very much!